# Remove rule sets from "Add or Remove Rule Sets"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

After experimenting with loading and unloading rule sets into C# via Nuget, my "Add or Remove Rule Sets" window has a bunch of rule sets from other solutions that I don't use anywhere, let alone in my current project:

[image]

Is there a way to remove items from this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remove the unwanted items by editing the following registry value: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\CodeAnalysis\RuleSetMRUList`

Comment: Note, in VS2017 it seems this key is stored in the Visual Studio application hive and no longer accessible in regedit: \REGISTRY\A\{13fed108-be43-0665-3440-a6629f788892}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_65aa1507\CodeAnalysis\RuleSetMRUList

I've added a User Voice issue to suggest supporting removal of rulesets. Consider voting here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32461772-rule-set-list-to-support-removal

Comment: Sadly the voting is closed and the issue is still there. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
- if the files with old rules set are present, delete or move from the current location. In the drop-down list are still present as files with full path
[Old rules present as files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZOKb.png)

- select one of that:
  [Good news is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6VsG.png)
- click "Yes" and work is done. Repeat for all other old rules sets.